# Remember last filename created by Hive on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, parquet

Hi I would like to know if there is a way that I can get the name of last parquet file that Hive created on S3 after I insert new data into table?

Answer (score -1):

Please look at the hive warehouse directory for changes after you write the data to hive.

Comment: I am having troubles with finding that file, do you know how can I easily get it?

Comment: Check for "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir" in hive-site.xml or execute "set -v;" in hive console to list all the properties. The configured warehouse directory would contain directories for each database and table. View the files created under your table name directory.

Comment: Thanks for help, it seems that this info is not set on emr that I am using it, I tried to setup custom path for some new test database but it seems like it is not writing anything into it. I will have to research more about it